# Alphanumeric, dash and underscore but no spaces regular expression check JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

Trying to check input against a regular expression.

The field should only allow alphanumeric characters, dashes and underscores and should NOT allow spaces.

However, the code below allows spaces.

What am I missing?

```
var regexp = /^[a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]$/;
var check = "checkme";
if (check.search(regexp) == -1)
    { alert('invalid'); }
else
    { alert('valid'); }
```

Comment: I like Andy E's answer below.  Also, you might want to checkout http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ for quick regex editing.  It's... pretty sweet.

Answer (score 193, accepted):

> However, the code below allows spaces.

No, it doesn't.  However, it will only match on input with a length of 1.  For inputs with a length greater than or equal to 1, you need a `+` following the character class:

```
var regexp = /^[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+$/;
var check = "checkme";
if (check.search(regexp) === -1)
    { alert('invalid'); }
else
    { alert('valid'); }
```

Note that neither the `-` (in this instance) nor the `_` need escaping.

Answer (score 24):

This is the most concise syntax I could find for a regex expression to be used for this check:

```js
const regex = /^[\w-]+$/;
```

Comment: Consider adding a note that your answer works also for international characters. I'm not sure in JavaScript, but in bash this works: `echo "abc-def  däf_ghi" | egrep -wo '(\w|-|_)+'

Comment: @IvanOgai based on the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Character_Classes#types) it looks like this only works for the "basic Latin alphabet"

Answer (score 19):

You should*n't use String.match* but RegExp.prototype.test (i.e. `/abc/.test("abcd")`) instead of String.search() if you're only interested in a boolean value. You also need to repeat your character class as explained in the answer by Andy E:

```
var regexp = /^[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+$/;
```

Comment: Actually, you should use the `RegExp.prototype.test` method if you're only interested in a boolean.

Answer (score 11):

Got stupid error. So post here, if anyone find it useful

1. `[-\._]` - means hyphen, dot and underscore
2. `[\.-_]` - means all signs in range from dot to underscore

Comment: #2 only apply if it's in square brackets i.e. [\.-_]  is a char in the range from dot to underscore.  But without the square brackets both are a sequence of three symbols, and they just differ in the order.

Answer (score 7):

Try this

```
"[A-Za-z0-9_-]+"
```

Should allow underscores and hyphens

Comment: Your solution helped me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try this one, it is working fine for me.

```
"^([a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9-_]*$"
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't escape the underscore. Might be causing some whackness.

Comment: Why do you say that?  I know the underscore doesn't *need* to be escaped, but  I've never heard of `\_` causing problems, in JavaScript or any other regex flavor.

Comment: Pure speculation. The expression looked fine otherwise and should not be matching spaces in any case, but I just threw it out there. Probably shoulda been a comment not an answer.